# Wordpress WP_query returns only the current page regardless of arguments

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress frontpage I'm using query_posts to show posts from the blog.

However, I head that using query_posts is a bad practice, so I'm rewriting the code using WP_query. The problem is that WP_query only returns the current page when I do this, regardless of the fact that I explicitly tell wordpress to look for posts, not pages:

```
<?php $que = new WP_query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>2));
    if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <p class="date">
                <?php the_date();?>
            </p>
            <h4>
                <?php the_title();?>
            </h4>
        </a>
<?php endwhile; endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incorrect, try this instead (do you notice the difference?):

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>2));

    if($the_query->have_posts()): while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <p class="date">
                <?php the_date();?>
            </p>
            <h4>
                <?php the_title();?>
            </h4>
        </a>
<?php endwhile; endif;?>
```

Comment: Ahhh omfg... Yes I notice the difference, and I knew it was something ridiculously basic like this that I was missing. Thanks for the fast reply to you and all other answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php $que = new WP_query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>2));
    if($que->have_posts()): while($que->have_posts()): $que->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <p class="date">
                <?php the_date();?>
            </p>
            <h4>
                <?php the_title();?>
            </h4>
        </a>
<?php endwhile; endif;?>
```